# Error de sintaxis sentencia sql UPDATE en PHP

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, update

necesito realizar una actualización en la columna stock_disponible de la tabla tallas en el momento en el que se realiza la venta, y tengo que restar la cantidad vendida del producto comparando el id de producto y su talla.

He revisado los indices del array de sesión del carrito de compra así como los tipos de datos y parecen estar bien, dejo el código de la sentencia y el mensaje de error que muestra el navegador cuando intento ejecutarla. Gracias por la ayuda!

Mensaje de error del navegador:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE),
>   expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or
>   number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\web\php\pagar.php on line 34

[image: Código sentencia SQL en PHP:]

Comment: Los índices de un array se ponen como texto, por lo que debes de ponerlos entre comillas. Por otra parte, en los campos de la sql tienes campos numéricos pero pones comillas, y te los interpreta como texto. Revisalo.

Comment: Lo mejor es que pongas tu código y no imágenes, luego por lo que veo no estas concatenando las variables, añade puntos donde terminas cada cadena para concatenar los valores de las variables.

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias por la ayuda, al final gracias a la función array_map() he podido ver que efectivamente los valores del array son cadenas, por lo que he convertido dichos valores al tipo de dato que corresponde a cada  columna de la tabla tallas antes de ejecutar la sentencia update, dejo el código por si a alguien le ha ocurrido lo mismo:

```js
foreach($_SESSION["carrito"] as $indice=>$producto) {
            $insertDetalles="insert into detallesVenta(id_venta,id_prod,pvp_producto,cantidad)";
            $insertDetalles.="values(currval('ventas_id_venta_seq'),'$producto[id]','$producto[precio]','$producto[cantidad]')";
            $operacion2=pg_query($bd, $insertDetalles) or die('la consulta ha fallado: '.preg_last_error());

            //CAMBIAMOS EL TIPO DE DATO DE ID, TALLA Y CANTIDAD A INTEGER PARA COMPARAR EN EL UPDATE
            $cant=intval($producto['cantidad']);
            $idint=intval($producto['id']);
            $talla=strval($producto['talla']);

            //ACTUALIZAMOS TAMBIEN LA COLUMNA TALLAS.STOCK_DISPONIBLE, RESTANDO LA CANTIDAD VENDIDA PARA CADA PRODUCTO
            $actStockDisp="update tallas set stock_disponible=stock_disponible - '$cant' where id_prod='$idint' and talla='$talla'";
            $operacion3=pg_query($bd, $actStockDisp) or die('la consulta ha fallado: '.preg_last_error());
            $types=array_map('gettype', $producto);
            print_r($types);
            echo "<br>";
        }
```